# Chainlink Node Job: requestData: while interpolating variables in JSON payload: invalid character '_' after top-level value: bad input for task

Tags: chainlink, toml

my fetch statement in my job is causing an error.

Log of the job run:

```
fetch bridge
requestData: while interpolating variables in JSON payload: invalid character '_' after top-level value: bad input for task

name: graphql

requestData: {"jobRunId": $(jobSpec.externalJobId), "data": {"query": "{ reserve (id: $(decode_cbor.reserveId)) { paramsHistory(orderby: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, where: { timestamp_gt: $(decode_cbor.timestamp) }) { liquidityRate, } } }", "variables": null, "graphqlEndpoint": $(decode_cbor.graphqlEndpoint)}}
```

TOML Job:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get 30-day Average Liquidity Rate 2"
contractAddress = "0x6eFc5873cB4eB9CE5024E9DeBA2139Aab235D84C"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="graphql" requestData="{\\"jobRunId\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobId), \\"data\\": {\\"query\\": \\"
{
  reserve (id: $(decode_cbor.reserveId)) {
   paramsHistory(orderby: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, where: { timestamp_gt: $(decode_cbor.timestamp) }) {
  liquidityRate,
  }
}
}\\", \\"variables\\": null, \\"graphqlEndpoint\\": $(decode_cbor.graphqlEndpoint)}}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="data,liquidityRate" data="$(fetch)"]
    mean         [type="mean" values="$(parse)" precision=0]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(mean) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x6eFc5873cB4eB9CE5024E9DeBA2139Aab235D84C" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> mean -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

Seems the request data part of my fecth statement is hitting an _ and not liking it. I am not sure how to format _ within the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to put quotes to "$(decode_cbor.graphqlEndpoint)" and let me know if that solved the issue?

Comment: When I add the quotes I get a TOML parse error. I assume it can't read where to insert variables  within quotes

Comment: What does your graphql  API return?

Comment: Command: `curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "localhost:8080" --data '{ "jobRunId": 1, "data": { "query": "{\n reserve(id:\"0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349\") {\n paramsHistory(orderBy: timestamp , orderDirection: desc , where: { timestamp_gt: 1642265213 }) {\n liquidityRate,\n }\n}\n}", "variables": null, "graphqlEndpoint": "api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/aave/protocol-v2-kovan" } }'`

Comment: Output: `{"jobRunID":"1","result":{"data":{"reserve":{"paramsHistory":[{"liquidityRate":"972287827221890442761195687"},{"liquidityRate":"972304600180672319853397463"},{"liquidityRate":"972304885273464365695551588"},{"liquidityRate":"972321659946071861558570003"} ...]}}}}`

Comment: Can you try to use a webhook job using your API to see if there is a valid response that way?
https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/webhook/

Comment: Thanks, made some progress. I am now stuck on one last parse issue:
`requestData: while interpolating variables in JSON payload: invalid character '0' after object key:value pair: bad input for task

name: graphql

requestData: {"jobRunId": 1, "data": {"query": "{reserve (id: "0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349") {paramsHistory(orderby: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, where: { timestamp_gt: 1642265213 }) {liquidityRate,}}}", "variables": null, "graphqlEndpoint": "api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/aave/protocol-v2-kovan"}}`

Comment: TOML: `type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
observationSource = """
    send_to_bridge [type="bridge" name="graphql" requestData="{\\"jobRunId\\": 1, \\"data\\": {\\"query\\": \\"{reserve (id: \\"0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349\\") {paramsHistory(orderby: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, where: { timestamp_gt: 1642265213 }) {liquidityRate,}}}\\", \\"variables\\": null, \\"graphqlEndpoint\\": \\"api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/aave/protocol-v2-kovan\\"}}"]

    send_to_bridge
"""`

Comment: My last issue is formatting " around the reserve ID. It get's messy with the backslashes. What I need is for the file to know the quotes around the ID are still within the original query quotes. If I use ' the job runs but my input is wrong and I get an invalid response from the API. I need to query in the format \"{ID}\"

Comment: If I then try this for example:
`\\"data\\": {\\"query\\": \\"{reserve (id: \"0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349\") {paramsHistory(orderby: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, where: { timestamp_gt: 1642265213 }) {liquidityRate,}}}\\", \\"variables\\": null, \\"graphqlEndpoint\\": \\"api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/aave/protocol-v2-kovan\\"}}"`

Comment: I get error in TOML file: `failed to parse TOML: (5, 1): unmarshal text: could not unmarshal DOT into a pipeline.Graph: Error in S55: id(19,xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349), Pos(offset=130, line=2, column=121), expected one of: =`